# Sending gmail mail to Drive as a pdf with attachment combined

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-drive-api, gmail

I currently have the following script that was working for us for a while. It was designed to take emails under a certain label, convert them to a pdf, and store them in a google drive folder. It works great. The problem now, is that it stores the email and attachments as separate files. We are trying to change it to where the attachment is combined with the message, so it is just one big pdf instead of multiple files.

The process was done manually for a while, but the load is getting too much. I have experimented with various codes but have had zero luck (I am not a great coder...).

```html
function saveEmailasPDF() { 
  
  var gmailLabels  = "Bill";  
  var driveFolder  = "Emails";
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + gmailLabels, 0, 5);  
  
  if (threads.length > 0) {
    
    // Google Drive folder
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);
    var folder = folders.hasNext() ? 
        folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);
    
    // Gmail Label
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) ?     
        GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) : GmailApp.createLabel(driveFolder);
    
    for (var t=0; t<threads.length; t++) {
      
      threads[t].removeLabel(label);
      var msgs = threads[t].getMessages();
      
      var html = "";
      var attachments = [];
      
      var subject = threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject();
      
      // Combines the thread into an HTML document
      for (var m=0; m<msgs.length; m++) {
        
        var msg = msgs[m];
        
        html += "From: " + msg.getFrom() + "<br />";  
        html += "To: " + msg.getTo() + "<br />";
        html += "Date: " + msg.getDate() + "<br />";
        html += "Subject: " + msg.getSubject() + "<br />"; 
        html += "<hr />";
        html += msg.getBody().replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
        html += "<hr />";
        
        var atts = msg.getAttachments();
        for (var a=0; a<atts.length; a++) {
          attachments.push(atts[a]);
        }
      }
      
      // Save the attachement to drive too and then add a link to the message pdf
      if (attachments.length > 0) {
        var footer = "<strong>Attachments:</strong><ul>";
        for (var z=0; z<attachments.length; z++) {
          var file = folder.createFile(attachments[z]);
          footer += "<li><a href='" + file.getUrl() + "'>" + file.getName() + "</a></li>";
        }
        html += footer + "</ul>";
      }
      
      // Converts the email to a pdf. All the conversation will be in one pdf not seperated
      var tempFile = DriveApp.createFile("temp.html", html, "text/html");
      folder.createFile(tempFile.getAs("application/pdf")).setName(subject + ".pdf");
      tempFile.setTrashed(true);
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check this [blogpost](https://ctrlq.org/code/19117-save-gmail-as-pdf?_ga=2.18901567.688276791.1550656952-1963610450.1550656951) to be able to achieve you objective. It's a sample code you can use.

Comment: This is the same code as used currently. The problem isn't saving the emails as a pdf, its saving the email contents (messages, attachments, all) as one single pdf and not separating the attachments as a separate file.